# Is it possible to authenticate a user after they've already connected to a SignalR hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to build a chat system for my asp site using SignalR. Right now I'm using the cookie-based authentication Owin middleware to authenticate the user on each request.

The authorization works for the hub when the client connects. But if the user logs out of the site, which I believe invalidates the session-id cookie, the user can still chat using the hub.

I need the user to be authenticated again each time the HubDispatcher's OnReceived is called or simply, each time a hub received a call from the client.

Knowing that SignalR connects using Owin's websocket which completely bypasses the Owin pipeline, I want to know if this is even possible or if I should try something else like add some logic to the logout method to inform the hub a user should be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a new cookie or a session id that you will exchange between the signalr client and the hub, so when the user is not logged anymore  you change the session id or you create a new cookie and if there is a mismatch you will sign out the user